# Yii2 apply validation rule on array of attributes

Tags: php, arrays, validation, yii2, rules

I use Yii2 and model rules for validation.
I have an `$id` attribute which is an hash value. The validation rule looks like this:

```
 return [
            ['id', 'match', 'pattern' => '/^[a-f0-9]{16,32}$/i', 
                'on' => [self::SCENARIO_DEFAULT]],
            [...some more validation rules...]
  ]
```

This works fine with with `$id = '17e94c10df492a39'`

But now, I have an array of ids, like this:

```
$id_list = ['17e94c10df492a39','27e94c10df492a39','37e94c10df492a39'];
```

Is there a way to use the existing validator rule for this array? Or is there a way to define a new rule using the match-validator on an array?

I know, that it's possible to write an own validator. But it would be nice, if this works with yii2 on-board resources.

Comment: If your model has only this rule, can you not just loop through `$id_list` and fill a model with the current id and call the validate function?

Comment: No, because this model has many rules. Sorry, my example-snipped was not ideal. But its fixed now.

Comment: In that case, is it possible to do the same thing, but only validate that one specific field? See the documentation: [https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/2.0/yii-base-model#validate()-detail](https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/2.0/yii-base-model#validate()-detail)

Comment: Yes, that could be an idea: iterate trough the array in controller and calling validate for each element.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you are looking for is core validator [`each`](https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/2.0/yii-validators-eachvalidator). This validator iterates through array and apply defined rule to each item in array.
You can define the rule for example like this:

```php
return [
   [
       'id_list',
       'each',
       'rule' => ['match', 'pattern' => '/^[a-f0-9]{16,32}$/i'],
    ],
    // ... other rules ...
];
```